# How to match square bracket without escaping with \

Tags: perl

When I am reading an input file in perl I got below line

```
u_pwrup_control/g_pwrup_bscan_cell[262]_u_pwrup_bscan
```

Now I want to find a similar line in reference file  using regexp .But it is not matching when I use below command.

```
while(<INPUT_FILE>){
    $k=$_;
    ##opening ref file in read mode
    while(<REF_FILE>)
        if ($_ =~ /$k/) {
            print $_;
        } else {
            print $k is not matching;
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to match [] without escaping with .

Comment: Could you give a specific example of what you are trying to match by editing your question?

Comment: $k has below  string u_pwrup_control/g_pwrup_bscan_cell[262]_u_pwrup_bscan and REF_FILE has same line but it is not matching as it contains [262]

Comment: I don't follow.  REF_FILE has the exact same line?  does `$_ eq $k` work?

Comment: But $_ will not contain exact word. It may be prepended and appended by some other characters

Comment: So could you give a specific example, so that others can recreate your issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `perl -e '$foo="abc[12]3"; $bar = "babc[12]34"; print "YES\n" if $bar =~ m|\Q$foo\E|;'`
YES

Comment: Yes it is similar to that

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the function [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). Alternatively, you can use `\Q...\E` inside the regex (more informations about that on [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).
Applied to your code :

- either do `$k = quotemeta $_;` (the `$_` is optional though), instead of `$k = $_;`
- or keep `$k = $_;` and in the regex, do `$_ =~ /\Q$k/`.

You didn't provide a lot details in your question, so I'm no guarantying that this will actually match what you are trying to match, but at least `[` and `]` (and any other unsafe character) will be escaped in the regex.
In particular, you *might* want to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) in both `while` after reading the lines, but it really depends on what you are reading.

---

But your code could be improved in many way, including :

- Always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of your script.
- Related to the previous point, but use lexically scoped variables (ie. declared with [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) instead of your global ones (not declared)). So write `my $k = ...` instead of just `$k = ...` (only when you declare it).
- Instead of doing your first `while` like that :
  `while (<INPUT_FILE>){ $k = $_; ... }`
  It would be much cleaner to do something like :
  `while (my $k = <INPUT_FILE>) { ... }`
  Using `$_` is convenient in a lot of cases, but in that one, it's really not.
- Don't use global filehandles, but instead use lexical variables :
  `open my $INPUT_FILE, '<', 'your_file_name' or die $!`
  And the, you can use them the same way as your old global ones : `while (<$INPUT_FILE>) { ... }`